# Начало строки в регулярном выражении

Tags: регулярные-выражения

Есть текст:

```
Bla-Bla

ERROR An error occurred while attempting to deploy the job
```

Есть регулярное выражение:

```
^ERROR(.+)
```

В программе, в прочем как и на сайте regexr.com последняя строка не берется! Но как только убрать в регулярном выражении символ начала строки `^` - то все работает. Почему? В тексте есть перенос строки (10-ый символ ASCII). Проверял [тут](http://www.onedollardata.com/encoder.php).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Для того, чтобы символы `^` и `$` срабатывали для многострочного текста, нужно указывать модификатор `Multiline`: `/^ERROR(.+)/m`

Проверять рекомендую тут: https://regex101.com/

```
/^ERROR(.+)/m

^ assert position at start of a line
ERROR matches the characters ERROR literally (case sensitive)
1st Capturing group (.+)
    .+ matches any character (except newline)
        Quantifier: + Between one and unlimited times, as many times as possible, giving back as needed [greedy]
m modifier: multi-line. Causes ^ and $ to match the begin/end of each line (not only begin/end of string)
```